# How to print subvalues in multidimensional PHP array depending on criteria

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I don't know how to ask Google so I'm asking here. How to print sub-values in multidimensional PHP array depending on criteria.

Example: This is array (country, capital city latitude and longitude) which I have created:

```
$capitals = array(
'Bangladesh' => array('lat_capital' => '23.810332', 'long_capital' => '90.412518'),
'Barbados' => array('lat_capital' => '13.113222', 'long_capital' => '-59.598809'),
'Belarus' => array('lat_capital' => '53.90454', 'long_capital' => '27.561524'),
'Belgium' => array('lat_capital' => '50.85034', 'long_capital' => '4.35171'),
'Belize' => array('lat_capital' => '17.251011', 'long_capital' => '-88.75902'),
'Benin' => array('lat_capital' => '6.496857', 'long_capital' => '2.628852')
);

$country = 'Belgium';
```

How do I get `$lat_capital` and `$long_capital` for `$country`?

**NOTE:** If necessary, I can change format of this multidimensional array. I have data like this:

```
Bahrain,26.228516,50.58605
Bangladesh,23.810332,90.412518
Barbados,13.113222,-59.598809
Belarus,53.90454,27.561524
Belgium,50.85034,4.35171
Belize,17.251011,-88.75902
Benin,6.496857,2.628852
```

**Additional question:** Is there any better solution how to assign `$lat_capital` and `$long_capital` for `$country` then arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its quite simple. But I think there is more to the question than I see. Please explain if you need more info.

```
$country = "Belgium"
echo $capitals[$country]['lat_capital'];
echo $capitals[$country]['long_capital'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to print out it like this:

```
echo $capitals['Belgium']['lat_capital'];
echo $capitals['Belgium']['long_capital'];
```

Comment: `'Belgium'` is just example. `$country` value can be one of _Bahrain, Bangladesh, Barbados, Belarus, Belgium, Belize, Benin..._

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($capitals as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key.', '.$value['lat_capital'].', '.$value['long_capital'];
}
```

that should do a job

Comment: Where's the `$country` condition?